# c# how to pass stored procedure parameter into api dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures, minimal-apis

I'm creating web api using .net core7 minimal api.
I create a function to call stored procedure which get from table in database.

I'm facing a problem to pass the sp parameter into the function.

Example of table(web_api.dbo.app_event):

| eventKey | sp | method | param? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /getstorer | [dbo].[sGetStorer] | get | false |
| /getsku | [dbo].[sGetSkuByStorer] | get | true |

c#

```
using (SqlConnection con = new(strConstr))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new("select * from web_api.dbo.app_event where isactive=1 and method='get'", con))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string _eventkey = dr["eventkey"].ToString()!;
                string _sp = dr["sp"].ToString()!;

                app.MapGet(_eventkey, () =>
                {
                    DataTable dt = new();
                    using SqlConnection connn = new(strConstr);
                    using SqlCommand cmd3 = new(_sp, connn);
                    cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                    connn.Open();
                    using SqlDataAdapter da = new(cmd3);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
                    connn.Close();
                    return j;

                });
            };
        };
    };
    con.Close();
};
```

sql for sGetSkuByStorer with parameter @storerkey

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sGetSkuByStorer]
    @storerkey nvarchar(18)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @TSQL nvarchar(max)

    select @TSQL='
    select 
    * from openquery(inf27,''
    select storerkey
        ,sku
        ,descr 
    from enterprise.sku 
    where storerkey='''''+@storerkey+'''''
    '')
    '
    exec(@TSQL)
END
```

I would like to put the sp parameter into the delegate handler

```
                app.MapGet(_eventkey, (xxxxx) =>
                {
                    DataTable dt = new();
                    using SqlConnection connn = new(strConstr);
                    using SqlCommand cmd3 = new(_sp, connn);
                    cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                    connn.Open();
                    using SqlDataAdapter da = new(cmd3);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
                    connn.Close();
                    return j;

                });
```

Final version

```
using (SqlConnection con = new(strConstr))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new("select * from web_api.dbo.app_event where isactive=1 and method='get'", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string _eventkey = dr["eventkey"].ToString()!;
                    string _db = dr["db"].ToString()!;
                    string _sp = dr["sp"].ToString()!;
                    string sp = _db + "." + _sp;

                    app.MapGet(_eventkey, (HttpRequest reqs) =>
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new();
                        using SqlConnection connn = new(strConstr);
                        using SqlCommand cmd3 = new(sp, connn);
                        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        foreach (var p in reqs.Query)
                        {
                            cmd3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + p.Key.ToString(), p.Value.ToString()));
                        }
                        connn.Open();
                        using SqlDataAdapter da = new(cmd3);
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
                        connn.Close();
                        return j;
                    });
                };
            };
        };
        con.Close();
    };
```

Comment: _"I'm facing a problem to pass the sp parameter into the function."_ - so what is the problem? Your code throws? The endpoint is not mapped?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to pass sp parameter dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject `HttpRequest` to retrieve request"s information :

```cs
app.MapGet("/foo", (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    //...

    foreach (var param in request.Query)
    {
        cmd3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + param.Key, param.Value.First()));
    }

    //...
})
```

`param.Value` is a collection, because is possible to call a url like :

```
/foo?param1=value1a&param1=value1b
```

Then `request.Query["param1"]` will be `["value1a", "value1b"]`.

Comment: Thanks! I success to put the parameter to api dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which will return `Func` with needed parameters. For example handler function parsing `p` query parameter and returning `string` can look like this:

```cs
Func<string, string> GetFuncForSp(string sp) => p =>
{
   // call sp:
   DataTable dt = new();
   using SqlConnection connn = new(strConstr);
   using SqlCommand cmd3 = new(sp, connn);
   // ...
}
```

And usage:

```cs
app.MapGet(_eventkey, GetFuncForSp(_sp));
```